# Problems with setting array elements in Forth

Tags: arrays, random, stack, forth, gforth

I am writing code in Forth that should create a 12x12 array of random numbers from 1 to 8.

```
create big_array 144 allocate drop
: reset_array big_array 144 0 fill ;
reset_array 
variable rnd here rnd !
: random rnd @ 31421 * 6927 + dup rnd ! ;
: choose random um* nip ;
: random_fill 144 1 do 8 choose big_array i + c! loop ;
random_fill
: Array_@ 12 * + big_array swap + c@ ;
: show_small_array cr 12 0 do 12 0 do i j Array_@ 5 u.r loop cr loop ;
show_small_array
```

However, I notice that elements 128 to 131 of my array are always much larger than expected:

```
0    4    0    4    2    6    0    5    2    5    7    3
6    3    7    3    7    7    3    1    5    0    6    1
0    3    3    0    3    1    0    7    2    0    4    5
3    7    6    6    2    1    0    2    3    4    2    7
4    7    1    5    3    5    7    2    3    5    3    6
3    0    6    4    1    3    3    2    5    4    4    7
3    2    1    4    3    4    3    7    2    6    5    5
2    4    4    3    4    5    4    4    6    5    6    0
2    5    2    7    3    1    5    0    1    4    6    7
2    0    3    3    0    7    3    6    4    1    3    6
0    1    1    6    0    3    0    2  169  112   41   70
7    2    3    1    2    2    7    6    0    5    1    2
```

Moreover, when I try to change the value of these elements individually, this causes the other three elements to change value. For example, if I code:

```
9 choose big_array 128 + c!
```

then the array will become:

```
0    4    0    4    2    6    0    5    2    5    7    3
6    3    7    3    7    7    3    1    5    0    6    1
0    3    3    0    3    1    0    7    2    0    4    5
3    7    6    6    2    1    0    2    3    4    2    7
4    7    1    5    3    5    7    2    3    5    3    6
3    0    6    4    1    3    3    2    5    4    4    7
3    2    1    4    3    4    3    7    2    6    5    5
2    4    4    3    4    5    4    4    6    5    6    0
2    5    2    7    3    1    5    0    1    4    6    7
2    0    3    3    0    7    3    6    4    1    3    6
0    1    1    6    0    3    0    2    2   12  194   69
7    2    3    1    2    2    7    6    0    5    1    2
```

Do you have any idea why these specific elements are always impacted and if there is a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better readability and less error prone: `144 allocate` ⇨ `144 chars allocate`

A mistake: `create big_array 144 allocate drop` ⇨ `create big_array 144 chars allot`

A mistake: `random um* nip` ⇨ `random swap mod`

A mistake: `144 1 do` ⇨ `144 0 do`

An excessive operation: `big_array swap +` ⇨ `big_array +`

And add the stack comments, please. Especially, when you ask for help.

> Do you have any idea why these specific elements are always impacted and if there is a way to prevent this?

Since you try to use memory in the dictionary space without reserving it. This memory is used by the Forth system.

Comment: I disagree that using `chars` is more "readable" or "less error prone".

Comment: 1) In Forth-94 the char size may be several address units. 2) Using 'chars' you show the intention that it's a block of chars (even if the char size is 1 address unit). 3) When you always use chars/cells, you have less chance that you miss 'cells'.

Comment: That doesn't explain how it's more readable or less error prone. It's less portable, sure. Not to provoke or suggest that it's an argument, because I respect 'conformance' as a desire even if it's not practical, but do you actually know of a Forth where the character type is multiple address units?

Comment: It's common for a newbie to miss 'cells' ([example](/q/54108389/1300170)) (i.e., it's more error prone if it's facultative). If the size is calculated, I (as a reader) see that the author didn't miss this point (i.e, better readability). 
In dsForth char size was two au. NB: [since 2017](http://www.forth200x.org/char-is-1.html) it's an environmental restriction of a system to have char>au.